# Error de protocolo de autenticación en conexión java -> MySQL

Tags: java, mysql

```js
package util;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

/**
 *
 * @author luigi
 */
public class Bbd {
    private Connection con;
    public boolean conectando(){
        try{
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            String url2 = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bdprueba";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url2, "root", "Abcdef123456");
            return true;
        }catch (Exception ex){
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

El siguiente es el error que me arroja java al intentar realizar conexión con MySQL, pero no he podido entender cuál es el motivo. Muchas gracias si me pueden dar una luz.

[image: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client Conectado?: false]

Comment: Nos ayuda saber las versiones de MySQL y del Connector/J.

Comment: Este error es por version, revisa la version del driver  y de la version de mysql si es compatible

Answer (score 0):

ese error suele ocurrir cuando la versión del conector no coincide con la de MySQL, te recomiendo verificar esto,  [https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.25[esta](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.25%5Besta) es la url de la librería de conexión de java con mysql de meaven, aquí podrás verificar las ultimas versiones del conector], si no es por maven la manera en la que instalaste el conector te recomiendo que lo hagas con maven o gradle. Para ver la versión del mysql en sí fíjate en mysql workbench.
nota importante: la mayoria de las veces mysql esta en su ultima versión y el conector esta en una versión atrasada

Comment: El link está roto, pero en esa página conseguí la versión que me permitió conectarme.
Muchas gracias!

Comment: me alegra que te haya ayudado, un voto para arriba me serviría y apoyaría :D, saludos